# M/S JK flip-flop response

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop

Could someone explain me why is the response so in the yellow marked area?
Since in the rising edge of the clock we hve J=0, K=1 the output in the falling edge shouldn't be Q=0?

It is a master slave flipflop

[image]

Comment: Is the JK state sampled on rising edge, then transferred to output on falling edge?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf is not what a master slave flipflop does?

Comment: that behavior appears to be incorrect ..... is this a school trick question

Comment: @jsotola I don't get it is the output signal wrong? Csn you draw the right one?

Comment: is this a school question?

Comment: @jsotola no it's not I just saw that on the web and I'd like to figure out why the output is what is shown (or maybe it's wrong, indeed I'm asking)

Comment: i cobbled this together ... it does not behave like your question .... http://simulator.io/board/IHiX6bxctD/3

Answer (score 0):

A J-K flip flop is like a D type flip-flop except D is now a J and a K input, forming a AND gate of sorts.

In your image /Q and Q stop changing states if either J or K is low, or logic '0'. In this case J and K are low, so the toggle action stopped.

Note that a D type flip-flop will not self toggle unless /Q is wired back to the D input. A JK flip-flop already has this feedback loop in place, but both J and K must be logic high or '1' to toggle.

Also note that either type of flip-flop will change states only on the rising edge of clock, along with J-K both '1'. A D type flip-flop is actually a latch and would pass the value at D on the rising edge of clock. It will not toggle unless /Q is wired back to D.

You should have a state-chart that makes the JK flip-flop behavior more clear.

Comment: Yes but I asked about a masTer slave flip flop And asked why the output is what is shown

Comment: I just explained to you and the image clearly shows why the way it is. You have circled an area where both J and K inputs are low, so the clock is ignored and Q and /Q maintain their current state.

Comment: do I have to ignore the fact that in the rising edge of the clock J=0, K=1? So is the master slave flip flop just a flip flop where I have to see just what happena at the falling edge?

Comment: If J=0 or K=0 then the clock is ignored and no change in Q or /Q takes place.